# Crystal Reports columns in details band, change direction

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

here's what I am trying to accomplish:

I'm working on a single page report using Crystal Reports 2008, and at the bottom right corner of a page, I have a subreport that puts 1/2" square bitmap images in details-band columns that might print one image, or up to five horizontally.  Right now, they print left to right.

What I would like to do is have them start from the right side of the subreport, i.e. the first image in the right corner, and additional ones print to the left.  Is there a way to make this happen? I've tried changing Section Expert > Details/Layout > Printing Direction between the options "Across then Down", and "Down and Across", no luck with that.

thanks in advance

Comment: As I'm understanding it, your subreport has only one details section print with 1-5 separate graphics in it, is that right?

Comment: Do you have one BLOB field or five?

Comment: single one that will print as many as returned by record selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this approach to work:

1. create a subreport that contains the image in the Details section.  Add a suppression formula to the Details section that reads: `RecordNumber<>1;`
2. hide all sections but the Details section
3. size the subreport to fit the image (1/2" width)
4. move the subreport to the right edge of the relevant section
5. link the main report to the subreport
6. right click the subreport and save it to your Desktop
7. insert a subreport and choose the one that you just saved
8. size it to fit the image and move it adjacent to the first one
9. edit the subreport, hide the non-Details section, change the Details' suppression formula to `RecordNumber<>2`
10. repeat steps 5-9 for the remaining 3 images (changing the suppression formula)

The idea is that each subreport retrieves all of the image row for the related row in main report.  you suppress all rows in each subreport but the one that you want to display.

Comment: I'll try this, logic makes sense, wish Crystal didn't make things so tedious. Thanks for the ideas.